# Concatenation with jsx don't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a react router like this:

```
<Route path={this.props.match.path} component ={CollectionContainer}/>
```

it works fine: supposing that this.props.match.path value is /home, i go to /home and the router correctly render the component "CollectionContainer"
Now I want concatenate this.props.match.path with another string, for example the string "a". I've tried in these ways but the container doesn't appear:

method a:

```
<Route path={this.props.match.path + 'a'} component ={CollectionContainer}/>
```

method b:

```
<Route path={'${this.props.match.path}a'} component ={CollectionContainer}/>
```

Some can explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Actually your first example should work. But are you going for `/home/a` or `/homea`?

Comment: are you using ` ` or ' '? In method b try using backticks instead of the single quotes.

Comment: method b wont work you need to use backticks instead of single quotes

Comment: yes i want go to /homea, i'm using ' '